# Can two directional antennas be connected without an amplifier to improve reception?

Tags: propagation, repeater, antenna-system

Can two identical yagi antennas be linked together to improve a cell phone signal?

The idea is to put one antenna on the rooftop and the other in the house, and connect the two with feedline but no amplifier. If the rooftop antenna is pointed to the tower and you use the cell phone while in front of the antenna that is in the house, will this provide a signal advantage for duplex and solve the common problem of low signal strength in a house?

Comment: My cell phone contract is with AT&T.  A number of years ago, actually I think prior to AT&T purchase by Cingular, my cell service at my home was very poor.  I complained.  They had an antenna that they could install in my home to enhance signal sensitivity (RX and TX).  I asked to get such an antenna.  But, instead of calling me back to arrange for the installation, I received notice of a new cell tower being installed that was supposed to improve service in my area.  I waited and the new tower fixed the problem.  So, they do have devices that provide for the kind of solution you seem to need.

Comment: What you are asking about is known as a *passive repeater*. They can work, under some rather special circumstances, but unless the two antennas are essentially back-to-back you need *serious* gain in order to overcome the feedline losses. They are mostly useful when you might normally rely on signal reflection but for some reason the signal simply isn't reflected to where you want it and you can't fix that by, say, adding an appropriate RF reflector.

Comment: Let me explain , I have a property where cell phone reception is poor in the house;  could I put a high gain directional antenna in a good signal area on top of the house and simply using feedline connect the roof top antenna directly to a identical antenna inside the house? would it improve tx/rx of the hand held phone. The phone has no wired connections to the antennas.